# Get update timestamp for an URL

Tags: ios

I have an URL/Feed, which returns a big Json data (100K). The data updates frequently, so I have to fetch it quite often. I'm thinking whether there's a way that I could fetch its update date only, so I don't need to download whole Json data if local timestamp is newer than json feed.

Thanks

Comment: It is only possible if the server supports it. You could create Yahoo Pipe which does the work for you, see http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/. Or maybe some Parse.com Cloud Code.

Comment: If the server could properly return a 304 Not Modified response, you should be able to automatically used a cached version.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this solution:

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/server-communication/how-to-download-a-file-only-if-it-has-been-updated